# Getting only 4 rows per idea from ideas table

Tags: mysql, select, php, greatest-n-per-group

i have a table of ideas that stores responses from evaluators and stores as one row per evalautor
For ex : Evalautor 1 evaluated idea A then in table record gets added as

IDEA A, COMMENTS , EVALUATOR ID

as single idea have 4 evaluator response and i need to show data in this format

IDEA ID ||. EVALUATOR 1 || EVALUATOR 2|| EVALUATOR 3 || EVALUATOR 4

1 --           Comments --      Comments  --    Comments   --      Comments

Need assistance in creating logic to get information in format given above.

Query i am running :

SELECT * from Toy_ideas GROUP BY evaluator id

but getting results as

Ideaid -- comments -- evaluator id

Comment: please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql and edit your post

Comment: Well i was looking forward a guidance not storyline @nbk thanks but it dowsnt fits my query

Comment: please [make the tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and also check out the the help center https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @AjaySinghRajawat - to get help writing queries here, you need to provide the details suggested in that page that nbk referred you to, otherwise the question will be closed as "lacking detail". Sample data and sample output would be useful, and/or otherwise giving more information about what you have and what you want. How would you want to choose 4 of the available 50 for that ID? Do you want 4 results just for this one ID, or 4 for each ID that has records against it?

Comment: @DavidSpillett: i need 4 results for one idea id , i mentioned that, and somehow i cant write query here as i hardly made any, i just tried using Having clause

Comment: See the tag I added.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please **always** include the version of the RDBMS that you are asking about!

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned, your question is lacking a lot of details. Specifically what is the criteria / logic you want to use to select 4 rows when idea with `id = DC889` has 10 rows, for example?

In any case, this will get you a random set of 4 rows for idea `DC889`:

```
SELECT * -- Replace * with only the columns you need, as * is bad practice
FROM IdeaTable
WHERE id = 'DC889'
LIMIT 4;
```